# Moment Generating Function of $f(x) = \begin{cases} -2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x} &: 0 <x\\ 0 &: \text{else} \end{cases}$

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I want to find the moment generating function of the following pdf to verify that $\mu=\frac{3}{2}$.

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x} &: 0 <x\\
0 &: \text{else}
\end{cases}$

So far this is what I have done:

$M_{X}(t)=E\left(e^{tX}\right)\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{tx}f(x) dx=\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{tx}\left(−2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x}\right)dx=\int^{\infty}_{0}-2e^{tx-2x}+2e^{tx-x}dx$

but after this is I don't know where to take the integral. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Factor out the 2 and separate it then use u-sub.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: After following your tip, I now have $2\left(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t-2}\right)$, but when I apply $M'_{X}(t)|_{0}$, I have $\mu=\frac{3}{2}$, which is incorrect. Any further hints?

Comment: You're off by sign. When you integrate, you're subtracting the value at $x=0$ while the value at $x = + \infty$ is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $t<1$. Then compute

\begin{align*}
M_{X}(t) := \mathbb{E} \left [e^{tX} \right] &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx}(2e^{-x}-2e^{-2x})\, dx \\
&= \frac{2}{t-1}e^{x(t-1)} - \frac{2}{t-2}e^{x(t-2)} \bigg |_{x=0}^{x=\infty} \\
&= \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left (\frac{2}{t-1}e^{x(t-1)} - \frac{2}{t-2}e^{x(t-2)} \right ) \\
&\quad - \left (\frac{2}{t-1}e^{x(t-1)} - \frac{2}{t-2}e^{x(t-2)} \right ) \bigg |_{x=0} \\
&= \frac{2}{t-2} - \frac{2}{t-1}
\end{align*}

Then the mean is given by $\mu = M_{X}'(0) = -\frac{2}{(t-2)^{2}} + \frac{2}{(t-1)^{2}} \bigg |_{t=0} = -\frac{1}{2} + 2 = \frac{3}{2}$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful. I see where I made my mistake.